# Is a git commit required if I rollback using 1) git hard reset or 2) git revert?

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit, git-reset, git-revert

I understand there are two ways of rolling back a git commit in remote repository.

Method 1:

```
git reset --hard <old-commit-id>
git commit -m "rolling back"
git push -f
```

Method 2:

```
   git revert <old-commit-id>
   git commit -m "reverting the changes"
   git push -f
```

In various posts that I have seen, there is no mention of `git commit` to be done. But my colleague is convincing me that `git commit` should be issued and that `git push` with `-f`. otherwise, the push will fail. Is my colleague correct? I am still doubtful about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Method 1 (not safe!)

Running

```
git reset --hard <old-commit-id>
```

will discard all local changes and make the current branch point to `<old-commit-id>`. Be careful with it, because it's a potentially dangerous command.

In particular, you should **not** follow this command by a force push in order to undo changes that have already been pushed to a shared remote repository. It would be [crossing-the-streams bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wrEEd1ajz4). It would be analogous to sawing the branch your collaborators are sitting on!

So this method is a big no-no, at least in case other people than you have access to the remote repo.

> Should `git commit` be used after `git reset`, here?

If you decided to go ahead anyway (don't!), you wouldn't need to run

```
git commit -m "rolling back"
```

unless you're making additional changes right after the `git reset` command (in which case you would also need to stage those changes before committing).

> Would I need to use `-f` (force push)?

Yes, you would need to use `-f`, in general, because the push be a non-fast-forward one.

## Method 2 (safe)

This method is nondestructive, and considered good practice for reverting changes on a remote repo.

> Should `git commit` be used after `git revert`, here?

Running

```
 git revert <old-commit-id>
```

creates a commit that undoes the changes introduced in `<old-commit-id>`. Therefore, there is no need for

```
git commit -m "reverting the changes"
```

unless you're making additional changes right after the `git revert` command (in which case you would also need to stage those changes before committing).

> Would I need to use `-f` (force push)?

No, you don't need to force push (no `-f` needed) here, because the push will simply be a fast-forward one, in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I do know the pit falls for `git reset hard`. does git reset hard require `git commit or not`. And you did not answer the second part of question, is `-f` required?

Comment: @brainstorm Cool. If it fully answers your question, consider accepting it.

Comment: ofcourse, It did not allow to accept right after edit. I need to wait for 10 mins..so here you go!!